# How to implement Kafka Listner to Pause & Resume dynamically using CircuitBreaker on downstream API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Lets say I have a RetryConsumerLisnter which is using **@Retryable and @DltHandler** to consume message and retry them based on certain exceptions and then finally move the message to DLQ.

Now After consuming the message it will be making an external REST call to get response.

The problem I'm trying to address here is imagine if the downstream is down continuously and we implement **circuit-breaker on the REST API call**, but here the **'Listner'  is still active** and listening to events.

Is there any way we can **pause the Listener** based on the CB Circut-OPEN ?

I have implemented CB on REST call but unable to connect CB state with Listener.

Answer (score 0):

The `resilience4j-circuitbreaker` throws a `CallNotPermittedException` when it moves to the `OPEN` state: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker

> The CircuitBreaker rejects calls with a CallNotPermittedException when it is OPEN. After a wait time duration has elapsed, the CircuitBreaker state changes from OPEN to HALF_OPEN and permits a configurable number of calls to see if the backend is still unavailable or has become available again. Further calls are rejected with a CallNotPermittedException, until all permitted calls have completed.

So, you need to catch that exception on your REST call and invoke a `pause()` of respective `ListenerContainer`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#pause-resume

Comment: Also see the `pauseImmediate` container property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pauseImmediate

Comment: Hi @Artem, for pausing we able to do it via CallNotPermittedException , how can we resume if the Listner is down and we'll not be able to make further downstream API calls to check if CircuitBreaker is Closed.

Comment: I don't know: as some scheduled task? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support